# Why do functions in MySQL not allow transactions to be committed?

Tags: mysql, transactions, commit, stored-functions

I have a function in MySQL that, if it doesn't have a transaction, works normally. When it is converted into a procedure with a transaction it also works. But, when it is a function with a transaction, MySQL returns an error that commits are not allowed in functions or triggers. Is there any reason for this bizarre behavior?

The function who works:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TesteFunction() RETURNS INT  DETERMINISTIC MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE Retorno INT;
 
    UPDATE Produto SET CD_Extra = "CD00472-5" WHERE CD_Codigo = 6;
    SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO Retorno;
 
    RETURN Retorno;
END |
```

The procedure who works:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TesteFunction() DETERMINISTIC MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION READ WRITE;
    UPDATE Produto SET CD_Extra = "CD00472-5" WHERE CD_Codigo = 6;
    SELECT ROW_COUNT();
    COMMIT;
END |
```

The function who doesn't work:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TesteFunction() RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE Retorno INT;
 
    START TRANSACTION READ WRITE;
    UPDATE Produto SET CD_Extra = "CD00472-5" WHERE CD_Codigo = 6;
    SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO Retorno;
    COMMIT;
 
    RETURN Retorno;
END |
```

Comment: It's a known and documented restriction https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/8.2/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routines-function-restrictions

Comment: I want to know WHY. Bill Karwin answered that,

Answer (score 1):

If you create a function with transaction control statements, there is nothing preventing a client from running a query like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM MyTable WHERE TesteFunction() = 12345
```

This would invoke the function once for each row examined during the query. A given query is atomic, i.e. it cannot be partially committed.

But it would make no sense to COMMIT a transaction *during* execution of a query. You can't do that.

Whereas you cannot call a procedure in that manner. You can only call a procedure from a CALL statement like this:

```
CALL TesteProc();
```

You can't use CALL in a subquery or an expression within another SQL query. It must be a standalone statement. So it can't have the same problem of committing during a query.

You might say, "but what if I don't use the function in a query's WHERE clause?"

You may not, but any other client can do so in the future. So the implementation must not allow such a paradox to occur, and the safest way to do that is to disallow transaction control statements in a stored function.

FWIW, you can't use transaction control within a trigger for the same reason.

Comment: It's the eternal fight between giving power to the programmer versus security. But I used an OUT parameter in a STORED PROCEDURE and it worked.

Comment: The other eternal truth is that if developers were allowed to do things that may be dangerous or invalid, they make requests for guardrails to prevent them from getting into trouble.